# SQL old table still appearing

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a really strange question. I have a dynamic SQL stored procedure that inserts data into a static table in the queried database. This table is referenced quite a lot in the query. So when I needed to change this table and add two new columns I deleted it and used the import wizard (Excel spread sheet) to create a new one and gave it that same name, so I didn't have to amend the SP. The SP works fine, however I also have this query outside of dynamic SQL and when I run it, it now fails.

At first I couldn't work out why but when I saw that it was failing on the `INSERT INTO` the newly created (but with the same name) table because there were too many columns to match the table. I ran a simple `SELECT * FROM` and it brought back the old table with the 3 columns it used to have and not the new table with 5 columns?

How can this table still exist if its been deleted? Its like a ghost table still remains?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add some screenshots of this occurring?  It is more than likely you are simply connecting to the wrong database or a view with a similar name etc.

Comment: Are you sure you added/modified the table in the correct database?

Comment: So frustrating! Every time I try to upload a screenshot its coming back with requested error! I've tried JPEG and PNG

Answer (score 0):

First check your temp table exists or not in your database.IF exists means drop your temp table and then create new one.

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype in ('U') AND id = 
  object_id(N'tempdb..#your_tableName') )
  DROP TABLE #your_tableName;
```

Comment: Thanks Mansoor but its not a temp table its a static table saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is known behaviour with views and can be fixed by dropping and recreating the view. Not sure why it is acting the same way for a table. Possibilities I can think of -

1. It is a view
2. The new table was not created in the same database

Try dropping and recreating the sproc, for what it is worth